# how to scrawl file hosting website with scrapy in python?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Can anyone help me to figure out how to scrawl file hosting website like filefactory.com? I don't want to download all the file hosted but just to index all available files with scrapy.

I have read the tutorial and docs with respect to spider class for scrapy. If I only give the website main page as the begining url I wouldn't not scrawl the whole site, because the scrawling depends on links but the begining page seems not point to any file pages. That's the problem I am thinking and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No, scrapy is only designed to follow link. You cannot find all the files that are being hosted - and it is deliberate design: only the person who knows the link can download the file. Depending on the hosting website, it may release API, which allow you to query what file a certain code maps to (e.g. mediafire), but you still have to make many queries to the server (the scale of billions is an underestimate, which I guess the server won't be too happy about it) to enumerate all files on the hosting service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two pieces of advise. The first is to ensure that you are using Scrapy correctly, and the second pertains to the best way to collect a larger sample of the URLs.

**First:**

Make sure you are using the `CrawlSpider` to crawl the website. This is what most people use when they want to take all the links on a crawled page and turn them into new requests for Scrapy to crawl. See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html for more information on the crawl spider.

If you build the crawl spider correctly, it should be able to find, and then crawl, the majority all the links that each page has.

However, if the pages that contain the download links are not themselves linked to by pages that Scrapy is encountering, then there is no way that Scrapy can know about them.

One way to counter this would be to use multiple entry points on the website, in the areas you know that Scrapy is having difficulty finding. You can do this by putting multiple initial urls in the `start_urls` variable.

**Secondly**

Since it is likely that this is already what you were doing, here is my next bit of advice.
If you go onto Google, and type `site:www.filefactory.com` , you will see a link to every page that Google has indexed for www.filefactory.com. Make sure you also check `site:filefactory.com` because there are some canonicalization issues. Now, when I did this, I saw that there were around 600,000 pages indexed. What you should do is crawl Google, and collect all of these indexed urls first, and store them in a database. Then, use all of these to seed further searches on the FileFactory.com website.

**Also**

If you have a membership to Filefactory.com, you can also program scrapy to submit forms or sign in. Doing this might allow you even further access.